# what should to do to use google map clustering

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I have a silly question. I've searched a lot and can't figure out whats the problem.
I have an android application and want to use Google Maps Clustering according to [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering). The problem is when I try to create simple Item class and implements from ClusterItem (according to example), it doesn't recognize ClusterItem interface. I add google play service but nothing changes.
Is there anything that I've missed ? Is there anything else to add to the gradle ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Introduction](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering#introduction) on that very page:

> The marker clustering utility is part of the [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility).

Where updated documentation and inclusion instructions can be found on [its website](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/).

For Android Studio, it is easy as adding a single dependency:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
}
```